# Is there any way to convert Powershell,Python script to Bash script?

Tags: python, bash, powershell

I have developed multiple PowerShell scripts for Windows OS

Check Memory utilization
Changing service state
Retrieving User Information.

i want to develop the same scripts for Linux and Mac OS, is there any way i can use existing powershell scripts.

Comment: [Installing PowerShell Core on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @Alderven : Thanks for the answer, i can't use powershell for execution, necessarily i have to write bash scripts, my questions is i already have powershell script can i convert them to the bash scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this link helpful:

https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/using-powershell-scripts-from-bash

It gives you a guide on how to install power shell and then some examples on how to run the powershell scripts in bash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i can't use powershell for execution, necessarily i have to write bash scripts, my questions is i already have powershell script can i convert them to the bash scripts? –

Comment: The guide I have link shows you how to run a powershell script from a bash script, but first you have to install powershell on your OS to have the functionality. Is this not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is not an automagical way to convert ps to bash nor to use ps scripts natively on Linux. You have to rewrite them, using bash, python, perl or whatever scripting language you prefer and considering that windows works in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your python script in the .bat file by doing the following in your .bat file:

"python.exe path" "the path for your python script" and then save it as a .bat file.

You can get the executable python path by typing "where python" on your cmd.